# can't play audio HTML5 <audio> on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, html5-audio

I'm having problems trying to play audios in HTML 5 with the  tag.

The audio is recorded correctly with the media file with compresion plugin: https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression, in the Documents folder, and I can even delete the files I created, so the filesystem is not the problem, I can write in the folder. Also I downloaded the data in XCode to check if the file was there, and it was, and also used the checkFile, with the File Plugin, and it says that exist.

But when I try to play any of that audios on the HTML5 player, I can't.

This is what I have in the HTML (I'm sure the audio file exist):

```
  <audio controls="controls" id="audio" style="width: 80%;">
    <source src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/LONG STRING HERE/Documents/audiofile.m4a" type="audio/mpeg" />
  </audio>
```

I tried with cdvfile:/// and withouth the file:/// or cdvfile:/// just starting with "/var/etc..." none of them work.

Thanks in advance!!